# How to show 0s in pivot table in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in my sheet: [image: Picture dataset]

What I am trying to achieve is a pivot table like this (where the columns are values of the "Date of P&L" column, rows are "CF/P&L/BS Account" columns' values, and values of the cells are summary of the "Sum" column):
[image]

I already figured out I can use the built-in pivot table module in Google Sheets. But I can't find a way to show 0s instead of empty cells. I ended up with this result:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Share a sample workbook. `QUERY()` function can give you same result.

Comment: @Harun24hr, thank you for your comment, I am working with ```QUERY()``` now, but the same question how do I replace empty cells with the 0s ones in the pivot table.

Comment: Use IF function like `=IF(YourFormula="",0,YourFormula)`.

Comment: @Harun24hr Doesn't seem to work right: https://imgur.com/fr21ucx, https://imgur.com/ZTPPF7A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what Harun24hr suggests with MAP through all your QUERY. Please adapt your QUERY if it's not correct, I tried to create it from your image in the comments:

```
=MAP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A2:G,"SELECT B,SUM(C) group by B pivot G format B 'MMMM-DD'")),LAMBDA(f,IF(f="",0,f)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried it, but numbers have somehow replaced column values (dates). https://imgur.com/gbpxqAc

Comment: Those are the dates! You just have to format that row by selecting it and going to Format - Number, and choose how you want to display them

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Last question, how do I group columns in this pivot table? For now, I just formatted the B column and got duplicates, as you can see here https://imgur.com/IPj25pj. It occurs because I have different dates, but they have the same month and year, and I need to group them. I am thinking about inserting ```SELECT TEXT(B, 'MMM-YY')...``` in the formula.

Comment: Pivot Year(G),Month(G)

Comment: `^1` from me. `MAP()` would work while only `IF()` should also work.

Comment: Just tested, you're right. It works if you wrap it in INDEX or ARRAYFORMULA. Great!