# Where can I find Pivot table option tab in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, excel-pivot

I am using Google sheets for learning Pivot table and cannot find the tab **PivotTable Options**.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: `Insert/Pivot table` ? (from the menu)

Comment: I am looking for Options tab which is mostly under the PivotTable name in Excel. I'm not able to find it in Google sheets. I have added the image for what I am looking for. Thanks. @Luuk

Answer (score 0):

Right next to View, Insert--> Pivot Table...

[image: Insert--> Pivot Table]

The picture you share is not Google sheet, that looks like Excel 97 - 03. In that case, select cells then Choose Data>PivotTable and PivotChart Report.

Comment: I am looking for Options tab which is mostly under the PivotTable name in Excel.  I'm not able to find it in Google sheets. I have added the image for what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You want to access that PivotTable option which is just for Excel. What do you need specifically in PivotTable option? Maybe I can help more directly.

Comment: I want to show 0 in case of blank.

Comment: Format & Layout -> Format-> For empty cell show

Comment: If I am not mistaken google sheet does not have any function like that. You need to write query for it. You can use @Martín 's  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897554/how-to-show-0s-in-pivot-table-in-google-sheets).